# Poker project using JFrames

Tags: java, swing, jframe, poker

I have a Java Poker Project. I programmed two `JFrame`s for the game and when you run the project, displays the `JFrame`s together instead of  the first and when it's done  the second. Any ideas?

Comment: I might have an idea, sadly you did not show the (relevant parts of your) code.

Comment: Well, call setVisible(true) on the second frame only when you are "done" with the first...

Comment: Present [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  Instead use a modal dialog for the first 'frame'.  This example uses a `JOptionPane`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TwoStageGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gratuitous splash screen");
                // the GUI as seen by the user (without frame)
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 200, 20, 200));

                gui.add(new JLabel("Play!"));
                gui.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Game");
                f.add(gui);
                // Ensures JVM closes after frame(s) closed and
                // all non-daemon threads are finished
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556 for demo.
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
                // in order display the components within it
                f.pack();
                // should be done last, to avoid flickering, moving,
                // resizing artifacts.
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: The Use of Multiple Frames is a classic, right up there with Charles Dickens.  "It was the best of code, it was the worst of code."